# The update statement works in SSMS but not in code

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I've been beating my head against the wall for 2 days now.  This update statement works when run in ssms

```
update dbo.DEMOGRAPHICS 
set ETHNICITY = (select distinct(ethnicity) from dbo.DEMOGRAPHICS where PEOPLE_CODE_ID = 'P000084716' and ACADEMIC_SESSION != '')
, GENDER = (select distinct(GENDER) from dbo.DEMOGRAPHICS where PEOPLE_CODE_ID = 'P000084716' and ACADEMIC_SESSION != '')
, MARITAL_STATUS = (select distinct(MARITAL_STATUS) from dbo.DEMOGRAPHICS where PEOPLE_CODE_ID = 'P000084716' and ACADEMIC_SESSION != '')
, RELIGION = (select distinct(RELIGION) from dbo.DEMOGRAPHICS where PEOPLE_CODE_ID = 'P000084716' and ACADEMIC_SESSION != '')
, VETERAN = (select distinct(VETERAN) from dbo.DEMOGRAPHICS where PEOPLE_CODE_ID =  'P000084716' and ACADEMIC_SESSION != '')
, CITIZENSHIP = (select distinct(CITIZENSHIP) from dbo.DEMOGRAPHICS where PEOPLE_CODE_ID = 'P000084716'and ACADEMIC_SESSION != '')
,RETIRED = (select distinct(RETIRED) from dbo.DEMOGRAPHICS where PEOPLE_CODE_ID = '000084716' and ACADEMIC_SESSION != '')
, LEGAL_RESIDENCE = (select distinct(LEGAL_RESIDENCE) from dbo.DEMOGRAPHICS where   PEOPLE_CODE_ID = 'P000084716' and ACADEMIC_SESSION != '')
where PEOPLE_CODE_ID = 'P000084716'  and ACADEMIC_SESSION = ''
```

but doing the update in the code doesn't

```
string updDemoRecords = @"update dbo.DEMOGRAPHICS 
set ETHNICITY = (select distinct(ethnicity) from dbo.DEMOGRAPHICS where PEOPLE_CODE_ID = '{0}' and ACADEMIC_SESSION != '')
, GENDER = (select distinct(GENDER) from dbo.DEMOGRAPHICS where PEOPLE_CODE_ID = '{0}' and ACADEMIC_SESSION != '')
, MARITAL_STATUS = (select distinct(MARITAL_STATUS) from dbo.DEMOGRAPHICS where PEOPLE_CODE_ID = '{0}' and ACADEMIC_SESSION != '')
, RELIGION = (select distinct(RELIGION) from dbo.DEMOGRAPHICS where PEOPLE_CODE_ID = '{0}' and ACADEMIC_SESSION != '')
, VETERAN = (select distinct(VETERAN) from dbo.DEMOGRAPHICS where PEOPLE_CODE_ID = '{0}' and ACADEMIC_SESSION != '')
, CITIZENSHIP = (select distinct(CITIZENSHIP) from dbo.DEMOGRAPHICS where PEOPLE_CODE_ID = '{0}'and ACADEMIC_SESSION != '')
,RETIRED = (select distinct(RETIRED) from dbo.DEMOGRAPHICS where PEOPLE_CODE_ID = '{0}' and ACADEMIC_SESSION != '')
, LEGAL_RESIDENCE = (select distinct(LEGAL_RESIDENCE) from dbo.DEMOGRAPHICS where PEOPLE_CODE_ID = '{0}' and ACADEMIC_SESSION != '')
where PEOPLE_CODE_ID = '{0}'  and ACADEMIC_SESSION = ''";
updDemoRecords = string.Format(updDemoRecords, peopleOrgCodeID);
pcCon = new SqlConnection(pcConnString);
SqlCommand doUpdDemoRecords = new SqlCommand(updDemoRecords, pcCon);
pcCon.Open();
doUpdDemoRecords.ExecuteNonQuery();
pcCon.Close();
```

Tried it from a stored proc also and it doesn't update the relevant rows either.  It is sql server 2008 and c#.net

Comment: What type is `peopleOrgCodeID`?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What does the error message tell you?

Comment: are u getting the SQL correctly assigned to  updDemoRecords variable?

Comment: @usr - I assume that the query will not update... no errors, but no expected result.

Comment: that's correct.  I would assume so.  I'm grabbing it after the string.format to see what it passes across.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to me that you are using an actual number (`peopleOrgCodeID`) - this will not have leading `0`es that seem required as you are using in the SSMS version (using a string).

So, if `peopleOrgCodeId` is an integer (or long) with the value `84716`, your `WHERE` clause will end up as:

```
where PEOPLE_CODE_ID = '84716'
```

And not:

```
where PEOPLE_CODE_ID = '000084716'
```

You can solve that by using a [composite formatting string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx), or passing in the string value with the leading zeroes.

---

I would mention SQL Injection as a possible issue, but if `peopleOrgCodeID` is indeed an integer, you are safe in this instance. I would still use a parameterized query instead of `string.Format`, however.

Comment: It's a console app that takes no parameters.  The people code starts with a P.  I edited the original question.

Comment: @Brian - So it _is_ a string? And you are certain `peopleOrgCodeID` contains the correct value? Did you use the SQL profiler to see what is actually passed in to SQL Server?